# QGIS snapping issues - newly created feature not visible

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, snapping

I have just used the snapping tool to create a new polygon feature in one vector layer, based on a polygon feature in another vector layer. I have managed to create features, but I can't see or select them.

In the screenshot below, the left image shows a green area on the active layer (UK-Land-oxford...). The right hand image shows an orange polygon from a different layer (longlist1) oin top of the active layer. I am trying to create a new feature in the active layer which matches the orange polygon in the longlist1 layer.

I have tried vertex and advanced configuration in the snapping options (settings in the screenshot below) and created the feature using the 'add polygon feature' tool. The new feature appears in the attribtue table of the active layer, however I can't see it or select it. When I select it in the attribute table, it does not appear selected on the screen. The layers are in the same CRS. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?[image]

Comment: At first check that you don't have a filter that "hide" the newly created polygon and that your symbology setting allow the display of the newly created polygon. Also check that the polygon is not simply below another polygon (in the same layer or another layer)

Comment: If you copy and paste the orange polygon into the layer you are editing, does it show?